# How to do enable gzip compression in google cloud platform?

Tags: php

When i am adding gzip compression code in my .htacess file then site is going to down and not working but same code is working in my other hosting.

.htacess file screenshot is below - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpYoe.png

Comment: If your web server is Apachi then you should write your code in .htaccess. if your server is Ngnix then write it on server projectName.config file.

Comment: I am using google cloud server.